# Look for the month and colour the cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am having column I with date. (30.07.2016). I would like to go through the entire column and look if it is for the present month. If it is not equal to august, then I want (jan-July) to be coloured green and the which are equal to august then white, and when it is future, then it should be yellow.

I tried the below code. It is printing yellow. It just looks for today and not the month.

Could you help how I can execute

```
Sub ChangeColour()

    Dim rCell As Range

    With Sheets("BU")
        For Each rCell In .Range("I5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp)).Cells
            If rCell.Value < Month(today) Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            ElseIf rCell.Value > Month(today) Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use conditional formatting for this? Should be easier than VBA.

Comment: I want in VBA.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the month of the date (cell value) against the month of today. Also today is a never defined variable here, so you will need to use `Month(Date)`.

For example:

```
Month(rCell.Value) < Month(Date)
```

Comment: I believe it should be Month(Date). At least in my excel today is only worksheet function, but not in vba.

Comment: sure you are right, just saw it after I posted the answer. Sometimes I should think first.

Comment: @ShaiRado Its still in yellow. and I am using this code in my workbook and not as function

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ChangeColour()
Dim rCell As Range
With Sheets("BU")
    For Each rCell In .Range("I5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp)).Cells
        If Month(rCell.Value) < Month(DateTime.Now) Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        ElseIf Month(rCell.Value) > Month(DateTime.Now) Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
        End If
    Next rCell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not working because `today` is a not declared variable here.

Comment: and you might also see the discussion of the accepted answer where we concluded that `Month(Date)` is enough and might be preferable above `Now` which also delivers the exact time. So that's exactly what I already answered.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell's date is text, the code would be like this.

```
Sub ChangeColour()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim m As Integer, vSplit

    With Sheets("BU")
        For Each rCell In .Range("I5", .Range("i" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            vSplit = Split(rCell, ".")
            m = vSplit(1)
            If m < Month(Date) Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            ElseIf m > Month(Date) Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub
```